# V8 Snapshot feature for Node.js server failure debugging

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I've googled for 'V8 mksnapshot' and found out that there is a 'snapshot' feature in V8 engine, also there is [this question here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/SfD5YSpU3Gw)

This feature seems to be an outstanding feature for bug reproduction in case of Node.js server fault.

**The scenario**

- You use 'process.dumpAll' in some error-handler of Node.js server, maybe attach it process-wise, maybe filter error events somehow.
- If a problem occur - all the V8 state is saved into a dump-file
- Later when you want to reproduce the problem you can re-run Node.js from this dump
- You than attach a debugger to Node.js, the process would be on in suspended state - same thing if 'debugger' is triggered, current statement would be 'process.dumpAll' function.
- Now you can inspect every objects' state in V8.

**I'd like to ask**

- Where can I find better documented (better than some chatting on forum) more info about V8 snapshots?
- Do you see any pitfalls for this scenario?
- What are the first steps should I take to implement a function 'process.dumpAll' and 'process.loadAll' for Node.js? (excluding knowledge about writing Node.js extensions)
- Maybe someone is already making or made some solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

V8's `mksnapshot` feature is not designed for postmortem debugging (but for startup acceleration), and I doubt that it could be useful for that purpose.

Coredumps (for crashing processes) and DevTools / heap snapshots (for exceptions) are in all likelihood more useful for debugging purposes.

There are some existing efforts for [Node.js postmortem debugging](https://google.com/search?q=nodejs%20postmortem%20debugging). Maybe just knowing the right search engine query can help you get an overview of existing solutions, their abilities and limitations?